# can not connect to my vps server vis ssh , Permission denied

Tags: linux, ssh, permissions, apache-http-server, django

i've looked similar question but none of them worked in my case
've build a website using django and apache but today it suddenly raised an error when i try to open my website it show only

```
Apache2 Ubuntu Default Page
This is the default welcome page used to test the correct operation of the Apache2 server after 
installation on Ubuntu systems. It is based on the equivalent page on Debian etc ..
```

before worked fine for about 9 month , i tried to connect to the server via ssh terminal

```
ssh username@my_ip_address
```

but it raised this error

> @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ @ WARNING: REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED! @ @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ IT IS POSSIBLE THAT SOMEONE IS DOING SOMETHING NASTY! Someone could be eavesdropping on you right now (man-in-the-middle attack)! It is also possible that a host key has just been changed. The fingerprint for the ECDSA key sent by the remote host is SHA256:the_key Please contact your system administrator. Add correct host key in /home/username/.ssh/known_hosts to get rid of this message. Offending ECDSA key in /home/username/.ssh/known_hosts:2 ECDSA host key for my_ip has changed and you have requested strict checking. Host key verification failed.

and i run this command

```
ssh-keygen -R my_ip
```

and the output

> Host my_ip_address found: line 2
>   /home/username/.ssh/known_hosts updated. Original contents retained as /home/usernmae/.ssh/known_hosts.old

now i try to connect it again but `ssh username@my_ip` and then type my password , it says

> Permission denied, please try again.

and also tried `ssh username@my_ip -p 80`

and raised this error

> ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host

ubuntu : 18
i appreciate your helps

Comment: Seems like "your" VPS is no longer yours ... Tell the VPS provider to nuke it and restore from backup.

Comment: @EugenRieck you want to say my vps been hacked ?

Comment: The host fingerprint doesn't change by accident: It is either changed on purpose or by a new OS installation.